# Android Packaging a jar with external dependencies - NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: android, jar, dependencies

I have created an Android Library project that I would like to distribute as a jar to my clients. My android project has some external jars (gcm.jar, gson.jar...) under /libs and I have checked "Android Private Libraries" under "Order and Export" in my project properties.

I have also created my own build.xml in order to create a jar including external jars:

```
 <property name="lib.dir" value="./libs"/>
<target name="jar" depends="debug">
    <jar
        destfile="bin/my-distribution.jar"
        basedir="bin/classes" >
        <fileset dir="${lib.dir}" includes="**/*.jar" />
    </jar>
</target>
```

I am trying to use the newly created jar in a brand new Android project. I then copy/paste it in /libs folder of the new project and run it. 
I am getting the following error message:

```
    06-19 22:29:49.925: I/dalvikvm(10108): Could not find method com.google.android.gcm.GCMRegistrar.checkDevice, referenced from method XXXX 
    06-19 22:29:49.930: E/AndroidRuntime(10108): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.google.android.gcm.GCMRegistrar
```

Using Project Explorer on Eclipse, I can see that my jar has been included in "Android Private Libraries" **WITH** the external jars. But it seems like they are ignored when I run the new project...

Note: I am using jdk1.6 for both projects.

Any ideas?

Thanks heaps.

Comment: Have you checked "Order & Export" of the app referencing the JARs? Did you disconnect the app from the library project and copy *all* the JARs into `libs/`?

Comment: Hi, I tried this too and it works when I copy all the JARS into libs/ of the new project. But as they are already "referenced" in my Android Library project and part of the generated jar, I am wondering whether there is a way to use them without having to copy/paste all of them in the new libs/ folder...

Comment: Your library project should also be checked under Order & Export. And Android Library should be on top and Src , Gen should be at bottom

Comment: Thanks! I would like to use a jar file so that I can easily distribute it to my clients. Referencing the Android Library Project using project properties -> Android -> Add Library works fine but it is not the way I would like to use my library. I just do not understand why the external jars within the generated jar file are not "used" and return an error @ runtime ...

Comment: I am still stuck with this issue and I am investigating other options. If you have an idea, please feel free to shout it in here! I will keep ou posted.